# Cancelling an asynctask with back button

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to do some tasks in background with `AsynTask`. As below:

```
class CheckTypesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);
        String typeStatus;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            Asycdialog.setMessage("First time initialization. Please wait...");
            Asycdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            create_database_and_tables();
            insert_in_questions();
            insert_in_answer_option();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // hide the dialog

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            database.close();
            Asycdialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Now the problem is that, if i press the hard back key while `ProgressDialog` is visible, it simply just closes the `ProgressDialog`. But when i check the `Database`, i find that all of my records which are to be inserted, are inserted successfully. I dont understand why the `ProgressDialog` keeps on showing even if the `doInBackground()` finishes its work, no matter the `ProgressDialog` disappears after sometime, but why is it so ??

My next question is that, if the data set that is to be inserted is not big enough, then why `ProgressDialog`still appears. Actually, i tested like this. I pressed the hard back key immediately after two seconds. And checked the database, I found that all the records were inserted. Why `onPostExecute()` is not called as soon as the `doInBackground()` finishes its work ??

And the last question is, i want to show an `AlertDialog` with yes and no `Button`, when hard back key is pressed while `ProgressDialog` is still visible. Then if, yes is pressed the `ProgressDialog` should disappear and the `doInBackground()` work should be stopped. And if no is pressed, then only the `AlertDialog` should be dismissed, and the `ProgressDialog` should still be visible.

Please help me solving my doubts.

Comment: See if this answer of mine helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15947770/450534

Answer (score 0):

If you place some line of code in `doInBackground` that only executed once and not in loop,there is no way to cancel it after executing your task.But if you have loop in it or other commands that run periodically,you can use `setCancel(true)` for your task and check the value of `isCanceled()` of task before doing your statement in loop.

I guess that when you close dialog,it takes some times to check DB records and during this time`doInBackground` continues until all records inserted in DB.So when you check your DB,see all records are inserted.

Also `onPostExecute()` immediately being invoked on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns(if task was not canceled).For example execute this AsyncTask:

```
class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            System.out.println("End doInBackground");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("Start onPostExecute");
        }

    }
```

But you added some commands before dismissing dialog that may consumes little times and also Activity transitions(dismissing dialog and foregrounding Activity) consumes some times itself.

**Edit:**

> And the last question is, i want to show an AlertDialog with yes and
>   no Button,...

You have to add a method to your AsyncTask class that shows an alert dialog with desired functionality and store a reference to task and also override `onBackPressed()` method of Activity.When onBackPressed() executed,call that method of Task instance.Although you know you can not cancel `inserting progress` in this way.If you want that no record insert to DB,you can remove them in background, after they inserted!!

Comment: okay, i got you. I am doing the background work without any kind of loop. But can you explain the first and second paragraph, i have doubt in.

Comment: ok. i understood. and what about displaying the AlertDialog on hard back key press...

Comment: @shree202 Please see my answer again.