# To force cancel AsyncTask shouldn't the flag periodically checked in doInBackground be volatile?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, synchronized, volatile

I want to force cancel AsyncTask. I see that you can use [isCancelled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()) like [in this valid solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770996/2401535) (which under the hood uses [AtomicBoolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

But I see solutions like [suspiciousSolution1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14280030/2401535), [suspiciousSolution2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947770/2401535), [suspiciousSolution3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6587889/2401535) where there is new flag introduced `private boolean isTaskCancelled = false;`.

And I started wondering - since that flag is modified in

```
public void cancelTask(){
   isTaskCancelled = true;
}
```

which runs on SOME thread, and is read in

```
protected Void doInBackground( Void... ignoredParams ) {
    //Do some stuff
    if (isTaskCancelled()){
        return;
    }
}
```

which runs in [WorkerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/WorkerThread.html), then shouldn't the flag `isTaskCancelled` be volatile (or [AtomicBoolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) as in Google's implementation).

Comment: yes, it should probably be volatile

Comment: As per google guidelines, AsyncTask should be used for doing very small function. It should not be running bigger loops or heavier tasks. For such features either use Handlers and Runnable or Background Service. The flag is present but it would be validated only at the start of your if condition. The task may or may not cancel immediately as desired.

Comment: Thanks but you comment does not answer the quesiton.

Comment: You are absolutely right to be suspicious of those solutions.  They are all quite broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes， it should be `volatile`. Otherwise a write to the variable in thread A may not be visible to a read in thread B due to optimizaton(by compiler, JVM, etc). See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html)

Comment: Yes.  `doInBackground` is being run on one of several threads in a thread pool backing an Executor.  It is unlikely that `cancelTask` will be run from the same thread.  That means that `isTaskCancelled` is accessed from multiple threads and must be `volatile`.  The `AsyncTask` framework itself uses an `AtomicBoolean`

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

> **Initialize**

```
  private AysncTask aysncTask;
```

> **Task Call**

```
   aysncTask=new AysncTask();
        aysncTask.execute();
```

> **Task Cancel Where You WANT**

```
  if ( aysncTask != null && aysncTask.getStatus() == aysncTask.Status.RUNNING ){
        aysncTask.cancel(true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, volatile. Considering that you are only using this to periodically check your asynctask. If it were multiple threads I would suggest using atomic fields. Pls see more information here: [volatile vs atomic](https://studiofreya.com/java/java-volatile-vs-atomic-variables/) & [Volatile boolean vs AtomicBoolean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3787435/2210080)